# Calling an insert inside of a ResultHandler gives null pointer exception

Tags: spring, mybatis, ibatis

I am implementing a filter which, under certain conditions, has to make inserts in some tables.
First of all I call my result handler like this:

```
    DateTime midnight = ...//date
    MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
    MyFilter filterChain = new MyFilter();
    handler.addFilter(filterChain);
    //query is a select based on the date passed as parameter
    session.select("com.MyRequestMapper.getAllRequests", midnight.toDateTime(), handler);
```

This is my handler:

```
@Component
public class MyHandler implements ResultHandler{
      @Autowired
      private AnotherTableMapper mapper;
      ...

      public void handleResult(ResultContext ctx){
         MyRequest req = (MyRequest)ctx.getResultObject();
         if(this.filter.apply(req))
              mapper.insertRequest(req);
      }
```

This insert gives me the following:

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
### The error may exist in  com/MyRequestMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.MyRequestMapper.getAllRequests
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: SELECT* FROM MY_REQUESTS where request_date = ?
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

...but I am performing an insert not a select! And on top of that the insert is not made on All_REQUESTS table!
Why is that?

Comment: Looks like the error is caused by the line with session.select .. Possibly your update works fine. The NullPointer is probably due to the mapping between table and Java Entity not working - I guess there are null values in your DB.

Comment: It can't be: there is a constraint on ALL_REQUEST table which does not allow for req_date column to be null. Moreover I added some debug breakpoints and I can confirm that req_date is not null and that exception happens on the insert() function

Comment: It could be any database field that is being mapped to your java entity - not only the req_date - that causes the NullpointException.

Comment: Despite what is stated in error log, error may indeed occur in the Insert processing, because the Insert is called while the handler fetches select results. Then for debug purpose, you should isolate the calls: `List results = session.selectList [...]; for (MyRequest req : results) { mapper.insertRequest(req);` then it will be easier to identify what the NPE is related to.